# Unity New input system Responds to UI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i make a game on phones and use a new input system.
Configured that the jump was to press on the screen and when I press on UI elements then the character jumps.
The game should only pause, but it turns out that the character jumps and the game is paused.

Used
`if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()) return;`
It works as it should, but an error pops up
Calling IsPointerOverGameObject() from within event processing (such as from InputAction callbacks) will not work as expected; it will query UI state from the last frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best chance is probably to do your own Raycast check the moment you hit your tap and assign your UI elements a specific layer (`UI` usually by default)

You can use e.g. [`EventSystem.RaycastAll`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.RaycastAll.html) something like

```
private readonly List<RaycastResult> uiHits = new ();

private void OnTap(InputAction.Context context)
{
    // Could also come from another input action of course if not using default mouse
    var pointerPosition = Mouse.current.position;
    var pointerData = new PointerEventData();
    pointerData.position = pointerPosition;

    EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointerData, uiHits);

    var uiLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("UI");

    // using Linq.Any which will be true if any UI layer object was hovered 
    var hitUI = uiHits.Any(o => o.isValid && o.gameObject.layer == uiLayer);

    Debug.Log("Is hitting UI: " + hitUI);

    if(!hitUI)
    {
        // Do your jumping here
    }
}
```